# Placing an ajax json object into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asynchronous

I've been trying to figure this one out since [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606901/getting-jira-fixversion-json-list-with-an-ajax-call-and-authorisation).

I can receive the data, as I see it under resources using `Develop > Show Web Inspector` on safari. But I can't seem to assign it successfully to a variable to use later on.

```
<script>
function getData () {
  $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://myjirasite.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      //async: true,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("myusername", "mypassword"));},
      success: function (){

      //Attempt 1 at outputting the result to an alert. 
      alert(JSON.parse(data));            
      }
    });

  }


function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return 'Basic ' + hash;
}

</script>
```

In a second attempt I assign the ajax call to a variable and attempt to print that out to an alert. No success. the alert is empty

```
  var jqXHR = $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://myjirasite/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      async: false,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("myusername", "mypassword"));},
      success: function (data){
        alert(JSON.parse(data));            
      }
    });

    alert(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));
```

I know that the issue lies with ajax calls being asynchronous, but I can't figure out how to write the callback such that I can get the json data into a variable to use later in via a different function.

Comment: you shoud mantain the variable data. It's where the return value from the server will be. Have you debbuged the cal in server side ? are you sure it's getting there ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira, I can't debug on the server side unfortunately. Production for my company....

Comment: And are you sure your url is correct ? try this code with a local server returning anything. If it works you'll know that it's the wrong url

Comment: Yep, definitely the correct url. I've used it on a curl script successfully, and I can see that data *is* returned, as I mentioned in my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `async: false`, as this will block the browser whilst your Ajax request is processed.

Instead, you can use promises, or call a further function from within your success callback.

Something like:

```
function getData(){
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://myjirasite/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("myusername", "mypassword"));
    }
  });
}

getData()
.done(function (data){
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));            
})
.fail(function(){
  console.log("Error!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var getData = function() {

  $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://myjirasite.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      //async: true,
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("myusername", "mypassword"));},
      success: function (){

      //Attempt 1 at outputting the result to an alert. 
      alert(JSON.parse(data));            
      getData.data= JSON.parse(data);
      }
    });

  }


function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return 'Basic ' + hash;
}

setTimeout(function(){console.log(getData.data);}, 3000); // Fire after 3 seconds to get data.

</script>
```

Comment: This is the same as above it returns `undefined`. If there's multiple objects in the json return is this likely to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$.ajax` actually returns anything - but I could be wrong. Either way, that's not too important, because you shouldn't rely on the results of an ajax call being available immediately. Your `alert` statement is firing before the Ajax request is finished - it sounds like you know that already.

When leveraging asynchronous calls (ajax), its a best practice to have any logic that relies on the data returned from the call to be done in (or triggered by) a callback (or as @Jack Zelig mentions, promises). This is what `success` parameter of `$.ajax` is all about. It will get called once the request completes successfully. You can also define `complete` and `error` callbacks - which fire once the request is complete (regardless of status) and once the request fails respectively.

So to summarize, your best option is probably this:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://myjirasite/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: successHandler
});

function successHandler(data) {
    alert(JSON.parse(data));
}
```

In this way, only once data is received will an alert be shown that will contain the data.

Comment: This appears to work, however the alert still displays `undefined`. In fact I replaced the alert for a console.log

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your successHandler, and see what the data is that is being returned (before the `JSON.parse`) - or just `console.log(data)`. If `data` is undefined, you probably have an error on the server side (or your url is wrong).

Comment: console.log(data) just returns `undefined`

Comment: Right...so your request is completing **successfully** in that the server is returning a positive response, but the data isn't what you're expecting. Again, verify that you're connecting to the right URL, and if that isn't the problem, then this is a bug server-side.

Comment: Well in my original solution at the top, I can see that I get the data, I'm just trying to assign it to a variable. Which isn't possible due to the asynchronous nature of the call. So this is about assigning the data to a variable *after* the server returns it.

Comment: Oh, well if that's the case, just declare an empty var outside the scope of your ajax call, and set that to equal data in your successhandler. You'll still need to be conscious of when you're accessing the value of this variable, because there is no guarantee that it will **ever** hold a value - hence my point about not triggering anything that leverages that data until you know for a fact that the request has completed.